# If you have a function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$, then is the function continuous at x=0?

Tags: continuity

If you have a function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{x}$, then is the function continuous at $x=0$?

On one hand, if you simplify it and end up with $f(x)=x$, it is continuous at $0$, but if you keep it in its original form, at $x=0$ the function is not defined.

Comment: You already said it. Since it's not even defined at $0$, it can't be continuous at $0$. It can however be _continuously extended_ to $0$ (by defining $f(0) := 0$)

Comment: Also, I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, a function is continuous at a point $a$ if $f(a)$ is defined and
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a).$$
As you already noted, your function is not defined at $x=0$, and is therefore not continuous.

It is however possible, as pointed out in a comment, to extend the function to a continuous one by simply defining $f(0)=0$.

Comment: It's worth adding that, in some contexts, one assumes that any possible extensions of this type have been made, irrespective of the literal interpretation of function is written: For example, often (and perhaps objectionably) that $x \mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is often used to denote the function $f$ given by that rule at $x \neq 0$ and is defined to be $1$ at $x = 0$. This is especially common when working with power series representations of such functions (e.g., of $x \mapsto \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$) and complex analysis; in the latter setting such 'holes' are called *removable singularities*.

Comment: @Travis: That is a good point. In practice, we are sometimes not very strict about removable singularities and the domain of the particular function, but there are situations when details such as these matter.

Comment: Yes, agreed, and those situations definitely include when students are learning the relevant definitions, as looks like the case here. (+1 for the nicely put answer, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about the expression $\frac{x^2}{x}$ then you are right in saying that it cannot be evaluated in that form at 0. In such cases when an algebraic expression of a function is not applicable you look for extensions that are either continuous, $\mathcal{C}^1$ or $\mathcal{C}^2$ or whatever property you want to preserve.

In this case you merely cancel out the $x$ from the denominator and the expression $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$ is equivalent to $f(x)=x$. Hence $f(x)=x$ is an extension of $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$ to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is not by the definition of continuity.
$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}$ is not defined at the absolute value of $x=0$ even though its $RHL$ and $LHL$ do exist at that point both being equal to $0$. It's a kind of removable continuity where by certain adjustments the function can be made continuous.